# difference between assigning method to prototype inside or outside the function

Tags: javascript

I have the function that acts as a base class and I want to add method to it. I can add method to function's prototype by name (outside the function) or without referencing the function's name (inside the function):

1) Reference name

```
Base.prototype.getResult = function () {
            return 5;
        }
```

2) Do not reference the name

```
function Base() {
    this.constructor.prototype.getResult = function () {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

I'm curios what's the difference between these two approaches (what are the implications)?

EDIT:
Updated my question to include example of what **Jacob Krall** suggested about this:
*This means `Base.prototype.getResult` will be undefined until the first `Base` object is constructed (so, for instance, you cannot call it on a different type of object using `Base.getResult.apply(this)` until after the first `Base` object has been created*

```
function Base() {
    this.constructor.prototype.getResult3 = function () {
        return alert(this.variable);
    }
}

Base.prototype.getResult2 = function () {
    return alert(this.variable);
}

var o = {
    "variable":5
};

Base.prototype.getResult2.call(o); //works
try {
    Base.prototype.getResult3.call(o); //doesn't work
} catch(e) {
    alert('exception is catched');
}

var base = new Base();
base.getResult3.call(o); //works
```

Comment: both are the same I think, but it does not make sense to try the second one as it recreates the function for every object created.

Comment: Thanks! >>as it recreate the function for every object created -- how is that?

Comment: The getResult assignment is run every time a new Base object instance is created.

Comment: @Maximus: with your second approach, whenever you call `var ins = new Base()`, the function is recreated and assigned to `this.constructor.prototype.getResult`

Comment: @KhanhTO, thanks, I get that now. But if I don't create instances of Base class, then they are similiar? In my second approach I'm not linked to the actual name of the function, which is probably a good thing.

Comment: *if I don't create instances of Base class*... Why would you have a constructor if you're not going to create instances with it?

Comment: _Why would you have a constructor if you're not going to create instances with it?..._ to act as base class and create instances with function constructors that extend it.

Comment: Ah, then you might have problems with the second approach, as explained in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, you are setting `getResult` on the prototype of every `Base` object. This happens at the beginning of the program execution, and is easy to reason about. I'd recommend doing it this way.

In the second example, you set `getResult` on the prototype of every `Base` object every time a `new Base()` is constructed.

This means `Base.prototype.getResult` will be `undefined` until the first `Base` object is constructed (so, for instance, you cannot call it on a different type of object using `Base.getResult.apply(this)` until after the first `Base` object has been created, which is strange). Secondly, doing it this way is wasteful, as a new `Function` is created and assigned to `Base.prototype.getResult` on every call to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you add them to the prototype they will be initialized once and shared between all instances. This will save CPU and memory, make it easy to change it for all existing instances and have inherritance (where instanceOf is true as Parent.call(this) would not).

To re initiate the prototype or part of it everytime you create an instance doesn't make much sense though.

What prototype does and the difference between properties defined with `this.someProp` in the constructor body or on the prototype is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711).